# CASE WHEN in WHERE with LIKE condition instead of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query with a bunch of OR's inside an AND in the where clause and I'm trying to replace them with CASE WHEN to see if it improves the performance.

The select query inside the stored procedure is something like:

```
DECLARE @word = '%word%' --These are inputs
DECLARE @type = 'type'

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE SomeCondition1
AND ( (@type = 'CS' AND col1 like @word)
      OR 
      (@type = 'ED' AND col2 like @word)
      ....
)
```

I'm trying to write this query as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE SomeCondition1
AND ( 1= CASE WHEN @type = 'CS' 
              THEN col1 like @word
              WHEN @type = 'ED'
              THEN col2 like @word
          END )
```

But SQL 2012 gives the error 'Incorrect Syntax Near Like' for `THEN col1 like @word`. If I replace `THEN col1 like @word` with `1` then no complaints but LIKE should return a 0 or 1 anyway.

I tried `SELECT (col1 like @word)`, extra `()`, etc with no success.

Is there a way to include `LIKE` in `CASE WHEN` in `WHERE` or should I just not bother if using `CASE WHEN` instead of the original IF's won't make any performance difference?

**UPDATE:**

This actually didn't make any difference performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are is a lot of info online about these 'optional' type stored procedures and how to avoid parameter sniffing performance issues.

This syntax should get you closer though:

```
AND CASE 
    WHEN @type = 'CS' THEN col1
    WHEN @type = 'ED' THEN col2
    END LIKE @word
```

Just make sure the col1 and col2 datatypes are similar (don't mix `INT` and `VARCHAR`)

You should compare query plans between the two syntaxes to ascertain whether it even makes a difference. Your performance issue might be due more to parameter sniffing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at info you've given but your sample won't work for me because I need to do `col1 LIKE @word` instead of '@word LIKE col1'. But I found a way to get it to work which I'll post now.

Comment: My mistake... I'll reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try nested case statements. e.g. based on your latest post, something like:

```
1 = CASE WHEN @type = 'CandidateStatus' 
         THEN (CASE WHEN co.[Description] LIKE @text THEN 1 END) 
    ... 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work, now just need to test if it makes any difference to performance. @Nick.McDermaid 's parameter sniffing is worth looking at.

```
1 = CASE WHEN @type = 'CandidateStatus' 
         THEN (SELECT 1 WHERE co.[Description] LIKE @text)
```